# How to create an "Apply"/"You have already applied" functionality

Tags: 7

I have been batting with coming up with a way to include a functionality that is critical to a job board-like site I am building. I have tried a couple of things that do not completely satisfy my own case:

1) Use Flags - and an action ('redirect to url') to send the use to the job application create page. Additional I set the off flag (once you click on the link) to say "You have already applied" and made it so that link was disabled for that user. The trouble with this approach is, a user could click on the apply link, have the job application node create form open, and then change their mind and not complete the form. The original job ad would still indicate that they had "already applied for the job"
2)Use Node Reference - I linked the job application to the job node; well and good, but here I could figure out a way to disable the link (and put up the "You have already applied" message/disabled link) after the user created and submitted their application.

Additionally I tried various permutations of Rules/Rules Link... but I still have found joy.

So basically, I desperately looking for help to to do the following is: **An "Apply for this job" button/link, that sends user to a job application page. On completing and submitting the application the user is sent back to the original job page where the link is now "You have already applied" and is also disabled for that particular user.**

I am at a beginner PHP level....

Comment: Try to do it with flag module.

Comment: I have, as I mentioned above tried that. Appreciate the thought